# wheel event javascript give inconsistent values

Tags: javascript, mousewheel, touchpad

I was working on zooming functionality with html / javascript / css
I attached a `wheel` event listener to my `div` tag 
and `console.log(event.wheelDelta)`
It works nicely with mouse. The `console.log` gives positive multiples of 120 for zoom in and negative otherwise
[image]

Problem is with touchpad
[image]
On zoom in gesture, it doesn't give consistent values. There are some `-120`'s in between. Because of this the zoom is very rough.
**How do i achieve smooth zooming or how do i get consistent `wheelDelta` values with touchpad**

Comment: Maybe adding a short timeout before displaying?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`event.wheelDelta` is not defined in every browser, deprecated and should not been used anymore according to [its Mozilla documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel). You could use the values `event.deltaX` and `event.deltaY`. For further information, please refer to [Mozilla wheel documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel).

I tested the following code in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. The values are very different. Google Chrome always returns as `event.deltaY` the value `100` or `-100`. In Mozilla Firefox it always returns the values `3` or `-3`.

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
    console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY);
});
```

I would not rely onto the wheel value but rather listen to the scroll event like this is described on the [Mozilla scroll documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll):

```
var lastKnownScrollPosition = 0;
var ticking = false;

function doSomething(scrollPosition) {
    console.log(scrollPosition);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    lastKnownScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    if(!ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            doSomething(lastKnownScrollPosition);
            ticking = false;
        });
    }
    ticking = true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var Scale = 1;

document.addEventListener("wheel",function(e){

  if(e.wheelDelta>0) Scale+=0.01; 
  else Scale-=0.01;

  // use Scale variable ....

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.wheelDeltaY` or `event.deltaY` 
`console.log(event.wheelDeltaY)` for mouse:
[image]
for touchpad:
[image]
Instead of -120 it gives 0. -120 which appears in the wheelDelta is actually the result of horizontal scroll(`wheelDeltaX`).(When you try to zoom in using touch pad, there may be slight horizontal motion too)
 
Do not zoom when its 0 and you will get consistent smooth zooming!